# Random vectors and sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be a random sampling of a discrete random variable. Let $\theta$ a parameter. It is easy to see that
$$
T(X_1,\dots,X_n) = (X_1,\dots,X_{n-1})
$$
is a statistic. My problem is when $T$ is sufficient? I don't know how to use the Neyman-Pearson theorem in that case or if it's a good idea to use it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are $(X_1, ... X_n)$ actually independent ?

Comment: yes! They are a random sample of $X$

Comment: A sample can be random but at the same time not necessarily independent. Consider the following example $(X_1, ... , X_{n-1}, X_1)$

Comment: @krashkov Random sample ordinarily means independence and identical distribution.

Comment: @ StubbornAtom Thanks, it is worth to remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T(\vec{X})$ is sufficient statistic if

$$
F (\vec{x}|T(\vec{X})=t, \theta) = F (\vec{x}|T(\vec{X})=t)
$$

By definition

$$
\begin{aligned}
F(\vec{x}|T(\vec{X})=(t_1, ..., t_{n-1}),\ \theta)
&= \mathbb{P}(X_1 < x_1, ..., X_n < x_n |X_1 = t_1, ..., X_{n-1} = t_{n-1},\ \theta)\\
&=
\begin{cases}
0, &\exists i:t_i > x_i\\
\mathbb{P}(X_n < x_n |\ \theta) &\text{if } \forall i: t_i < x_i
\end{cases}\\
&=
\begin{cases}
0, &\exists i:t_i > x_i\\
F(x_n|\theta) &\text{if } \forall i: t_i < x_i
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

If $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ are independent, then $T(X_1, ..., X_n)$ is not sufficient in any case.

Comment: In the second equality, you say that the first expression is $P(X_n < x_n|\theta)$, but I think that should be $P(X_1<t_1|\theta)\cdots P(X_{n-1} < t_{n-1}|\theta)P(X_n < x_n|\theta)$, why disapear all terms which have the form $P(X_{i} < t_i|\theta)$?

Comment: Suppose, that $t_i < x_i$ then $P(X_i < x_i|X_i = t_i, \theta) = P(t_i < x_i| \theta) = 1$ because of the initial assumption. Contrary if $t_i > x_i$ then $P(X_i < x_i|X_i = t_i, \theta) = P(t_i < x_i| \theta) = 0$. Did you catch the idea ?

Comment: yeees! Thank you!